# How to access array in PLSQL

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

please, is it possible to access single values in varray?

Something like `newVariable := myArray(value2)` --> this will assign second value in array into new varible...

I also need something like this:

```
FOR CYCLE...
x++
newVariable(x) := myArray(value(x))
END FOR CYCLE
```

Is it possible?

Thx, I'm student of information technologies and I'm trying to solve this. Don't know where to look...

Comment: "*Don't know where to look*". What about the manual? http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/composites.htm#CHDEIJHD

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the oracle online documentation, the varray type is the type among other collection types in PL/SQL used for creating array like objects(I mean array as we understand it in other classic programming languages such as C, Java, etc.). Except that the length can varry from 0 to a maximum size specified during its definition.

Here is an example:

```
DECLARE
    SUBTYPE country_ty IS VARCHAR2(50);
    TYPE countries_varr_ty IS VARRAY(10) OF country_ty;
    l_varr_countries countries_varr_ty :=
        countries_varr_ty
        (
            'Iran', 'France', 'United Kingdom', 'United States', 'Germany',
            'Spain', 'Canada', 'Australia', 'South Africa', 'Afganistan'
        );
    l_country country_ty;
BEGIN
    FOR counter IN l_varr_countries.FIRST .. l_varr_countries.LAST
    LOOP
        l_country := l_varr_countries(counter);
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('The current value in the array is: ' 
            || l_country);
    END LOOP;
END;
/
```

For more information on varrays you can refer to the following link:

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/composites.htm#CHDEIJHD

Regards,

Dariyoosh